# how to check a facebook user allowed subscribe

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Given a facebook user url, take https://www.facebook.com/zuck as example,
if the facebook user allowed subscribe, then show the subscribe button(using generated code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) otherwise just show the facebook user url.
Is it possible with the facebook jsdk?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see that info available anywhere, neither in the Graph API or FQL user object/table, so I guess there is no way of straight forward asking for this yet.

If the user profile you’ve given does not allow subscriptions though, the plugin element that get’s rendered has a very small width (clear to see if you choose color-scheme “dark” on the mentioned page) – so maybe using the HTML5 version of the plugin it should be possible to use JS to ask for the width of that element, and use that info to make an educated guess to whether the user allows subscribing or not …

Comment: I tried reading the facebook jsdk source, found that facebook jsdk use a iframe to contain the request result. I can't find a way to hook the iframe loaded event(tried FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render'), FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.parse'),FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.iframeWidget.render') none is useful) and check its' content(can't access cross domain) after loaded, any suggestion?

Comment: Like I said, the only way I can see to possibly achieve what you want is to read the dimensions of the embedding element, which belongs to your own DOM, and try to get to conclusions from that.